# how do you write a State of the Art section in this particular case?

Tags: writing

How can I write an adequate State of the Art section in the following case for the field of CS? Let´s suppose that I am writing an article that solely relies on using classic Machine Learning techniques to detect spam. However, nowadays, the research has pointed out the use of advanced Deep Learning methods such as transformers, but I will not like to point my research toward that path. In this case, what would be the recommended way to sketch my State of the Art? I have been thinking of two possible ways:

1. To briefly mention the studies that relate to Deep Learning at the beginning of my State of the Art section and then narrow the description of these studies and focus more on those that used classical ML techniques. These articles, of course, would be outdated compared to the DL ones, but I am trying to avoid a critique of my work that would point out why I have not used DL techniques if I mention them in the State of the Art.
2. To not describe these DL works and only focus on those related to ML techniques.

Which one could be a feasible option in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest a third way, a variation on your first option. Explain that you are extending classical ML techniques in this paper (and why) and give the state of the art on that. At the end, mention that current research has been exploring a different path, DL... Give a few sentences about where that is currently.

Say the things most important to your paper first, not last.

It would probably be a mistake to ignore Deep Learning.

For a thesis, rather than a paper, you have a lot more space, probably, to be fairly complete on both.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can not omit the current state-of-the-art solutions from the comparison entirely. The elephant is in the room.

The main question, of course, is why are you using something else in the first place. Yes, there are very good reasons for opting out of "black box" modern machine learning techniques, but you have to make a convincing argument here. What is desirable, but not achievable by those deep learning models?

And then there is a problem of implementation. It is hard to keep up with the AI/ML field if you do not collaborate with a lab doing specifically that, and as a result, articles with poorly implemented and/or woefully outdated models are all too common. This consideration should go in the planning phase of your research: do you have resources to properly reproduce the current state-of-the-art? If no, how can you compare your results to it? Should you be using some well-known public dataset? If your work is contingent on collecting your own data, maybe opt for an indirect comparison based on the existing research to make statements about that data.

I have now spent a few years preaching that the research dealing with machine learning must either improve on SOTA or be still valuable in some other way in several years when the performance goalposts move a lot. Coming from that perspective, it is perfectly valid to not pursue the "hot" topic as long as you could still provide the sufficient research motivation. Publishing papers just to heat up the interest for ML in your field of study seems superfluous at this point.